# Attempting to simplify user command system for java text game by replacing switch with hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, switch-statement, console-application

I have looked at numerous posts here on and other sites on similar topics but haven't found answers for this specific issue.
I am messing around with a Java text game in the console, and am trying to create an efficient movement/command system. As the code in the GamePlay class shows I am trying to make a 2X2 map of Room objects, by creating four rooms and then passing adjacent rooms based on direction to corresponding setters in the Rooms class. As you can see from the first example of the GamePlay class, I am accepting console input for a direction("n","s","e","w")
,using the switch to check the players current room, and then checking for an adjacent room based on the direction entered, before finally setting the player's location to the adjacent room if it exists.
This system works exactly how I want it to, but having so many switch cases with very similar functions seems excessive. What I was thinking may be a more compact solution is to store the common movement commands as keys in a hashmap with functions to check for adjacent rooms as the values(See GamePlayExample2). Though the method values in the hashmap are the same, the outcome is different than when using the switch case. When trying to set the player's location with the hashmap, it seems like a coin flip whether it will choose the right room, and eventually, it starts returning that there are no possible movements, despite there being valid moves. I also attempted to do this hashMap system, storing all of my rooms in an arrayList and using their index numbers as hashMap values, and -1 to indicate a non adjacent room. That attempt had the same outcome. I am not receiving any errors, this seems like a logic issue. Apologies for the long post, thanks ahead of time.

```
public class Hero {
    
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Rooms location;
    
    public Hero(String name, String description, Rooms location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Rooms getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Rooms location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

```
public class Rooms {
    
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Rooms north;
    private Rooms south;
    private Rooms east;
    private Rooms west;
    
    Rooms(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Rooms getNorth() {
        return north;
    }

    public void setNorth(Rooms north) {
        this.north = north;
    }

    public Rooms getSouth() {
        return south;
    }

    public void setSouth(Rooms south) {
        this.south = south;
    }

    public Rooms getEast() {
        return east;
    }

    public void setEast(Rooms east) {
        this.east = east;
    }

    public Rooms getWest() {
        return west;
    }

    public void setWest(Rooms west) {
        this.west = west;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GamePlay {
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Rooms front = new Rooms("front", "This is the front");
    Rooms garden = new Rooms("Garden", "This is the garden");
    Rooms kitchen = new Rooms("kitchen", "This is the kitchen");
    Rooms diningRoom = new Rooms("Dining room", "This is the dining room");
    Hero Ron = new Hero("Ron", "The hero!", front);
    
    public void Movement() {
        
        front.setNorth(diningRoom);
        front.setWest(garden);
        
        diningRoom.setWest(kitchen);
        diningRoom.setSouth(front);
        
        kitchen.setEast(diningRoom);
        kitchen.setSouth(garden);
        
        garden.setEast(front);
        garden.setNorth(kitchen);
        
        while(true) {
            
            System.out.println("Your location: " + Ron.getLocation().getName());
            System.out.println("Which way?: ");
            String moveChoice = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            
            switch(moveChoice) {
            
                case "n":
                    
                    if(Ron.getLocation().getNorth() != null) {
                        Ron.setLocation(Ron.getLocation().getNorth());
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("You cant go that way!!");
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case "s":
                    
                    if(Ron.getLocation().getSouth() != null) {
                        Ron.setLocation(Ron.getLocation().getSouth());
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("You cant go that way!!");
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case "e":
                    
                    if(Ron.getLocation().getEast() != null) {
                        Ron.setLocation(Ron.getLocation().getEast());
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("You cant go that way!!");
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case "w":
                    if(Ron.getLocation().getWest() != null) {
                        Ron.setLocation(Ron.getLocation().getWest());
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("You cant go that way!!");
                    }
                    break;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GamePlayExample2 {
        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap <String, Rooms> commands = new HashMap <String, Rooms> ();
    Rooms front = new Rooms("front", "This is the front");
    Rooms garden = new Rooms("Garden", "This is the garden");
    Rooms kitchen = new Rooms("kitchen", "This is the kitchen");
    Rooms diningRoom = new Rooms("Dining room", "This is the dining room");
    Hero Ron = new Hero("Ron", "The hero!", front);
        
    public void Movement() {
        
        front.setNorth(diningRoom);
        front.setWest(garden);
            
        diningRoom.setWest(kitchen);
        diningRoom.setSouth(front);
            
        kitchen.setEast(diningRoom);
        kitchen.setSouth(garden);
            
        garden.setEast(front);
        garden.setNorth(kitchen);
            
        commands.put("n", Ron.getLocation().getNorth());
        commands.put("s", Ron.getLocation().getSouth());
        commands.put("e", Ron.getLocation().getEast());
        commands.put("w", Ron.getLocation().getWest());
        
        while(true) {
                
            System.out.println("Your location: " + Ron.getLocation().getName());
            System.out.println("Which way?: ");
            String moveChoice = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            
            if(commands.containsKey(moveChoice)) {
                if(commands.get(moveChoice) != null) {
                    Ron.setLocation(commands.get(moveChoice));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("You can't go that way!");
                }
            }else {
                System.out.println("That command does not exist!");
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't associate the command with the room that it goes to, because that will change every time you move. Unless you're going to re-populate the map after every move.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DavidConrad Hey David, thanks for your quick response. Sorry, I can be a little dense sometimes, I'm not sure I fully grasp the first half of your comment. Could you expand on your meaning please?

Comment: Sure. In your second example, right before the `while` loop, you put rooms in the map associated with `n`, `s`, `e`, and `w`, but as soon as "Ron" moves, those will no longer be the correct destinations for his new location. But you keep using them every time around the loop.

Comment: @DavidConrad Oh gotcha. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks very much!